# Self-Hosted FontAwesome Icons Not Rendering on OS X Sierra

Tags: css, font-awesome, webfonts, macos-sierra

For the life of me, I can't get self-hosted FontAwesome icons to render in my Angular 2 application.

My Directory structure for these fonts is:

`/src/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/`

WebPack is using `/src/` as the root when serving the site locally.

To reduce http requests in my app, I have inlined the minified FontAwesome css in my index.html file, and specified the `@font-face` as such in index.html:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: local('FontAwesome'),
    url('/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),
    url('/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),
    url('/assets/app/fonts/font-awesome/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

As you can see, the paths to the font files are root relative, and I am able to download the individual font files via those URLs directly, so I'm pretty sure this isn't a path issue.

In Chrome on OS X, I get squares. In Safari, I don't get any icons at all. I have combed through lots of articles with lots of people experiencing various issues similar to mine, but nothing has helped so far.

Even if I supply a specific loader for fonts:

```
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: ['url']
}
```

it still doesn't work. On Windows 8.1/10 and Linux (Ubuntu / Mint), everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the CDN-based version of Font Awesome as self-hosting wasn't working in OS X or for Cordova builds of my app.

Comment: Thanks ! Any idea why that happens? ([related](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1447#issuecomment-1454294180))

Comment: No. We still don't self-host FontAwesome to this day